# Binary Tree (not search) max function

Tags: c++, max, binary-tree

I'm getting a segmentation fault with my code and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to find the max value in a regular binary tree that is not ordered.

```
tnode<int> *maxT(tnode<int> *t)
{
    if (t == NULL) return NULL; 

    tnode<int> *left = maxT(t->left); 
    tnode<int> *right = maxT(t->right); 

    if (left->nodeValue > right->nodeValue)
    {
        return maxT(left);
    }
    if (left->nodeValue < right->nodeValue)
    {
        return maxT(right);
    }

 }
```

Comment: What if either `left` or `right` is `NULL`?

Comment: Check the return value if t is NULL, should you be returning NULL?

Comment: BTW, if `left->nodeValue == right->nodeValue`, there is no return value.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamentals of the algorithm are fairly straight forward. Because the tree is unordered, *all* nodes must be visited, with the following preconditions:

- A null node pointer results in null as an answer.
- Else a node with no children results in the current node
- Else result is the max of the node compared to the max of its children.

Given that, I'm pretty sure this is what you're trying to do:

```
template<typename T>
tnode<T>* maxT(const tnode<T>* t)
{
    if (!t)
        return nullptr;

    tnode<T>* lmax = maxT(t->left);
    tnode<T>* rmax = maxT(t->right);
    tnode<T>* cmax = (lmax && rmax) 
                   ? ((rmax->nodeValue < lmax->nodeValue ? lmax : rmax))
                   : (lmax ? lmax : rmax);
    return (!cmax || (cmax->nodeValue < t->nodeValue) ? t : cmax);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tnode<int> *maxT(tnode<int> *t)
{
  if (t->right == NULL && t->left == NULL) //leaf node
    return t->nodeValue;

  else if (t->right == NULL) //no right subtree
    return MAX(t->nodeValue, maxT(t->left))

  else if (t->left == NULL) //no left subtree
    return MAX(t->nodeValue, maxT(t->right))

  else 
    return MAX(maxT(t->right), maxT(t->left));
}
```

In your case, what happens if a node doesn't have a right or left child. Then either **node->right == NULL** or **node->left == NULL**. Yet you are trying to access **left->nodeValue** or **right->nodeValue**.

Comment: What does that function *return* again?